# Adjusting / Re-Sizing SWAP Memory in EC2 AMI

Tags: linux, memory, amazon-ec2, swap

I have created a swap memory of 1 GB on my EC2 Instance, but i need to extend it or re-size it, like adding 2 or 3 more GBs in to that.

I couldn't find any solution to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

After searching over, i have re-run the swap commands and system over writes the configuration with new swap memory settings.